# Is it possible to sort only a range and not entire row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

UPDATE:

Solved the challenge with this code:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.getSheetByName("sheetName").getRange("F6:J12").sort({column: 6, ascending: false});
```

---o---

As mentioned in the topic, I need to sort only a range (`F6:J12`, green frame in image), without affecting the whole row(s)(`A6:J12`, red frame in image). Is that possible?

I have experimented with Google sheets build-in sort function, to see if I could make a macro and get some ideas from the code, but with no luck. I mark the range I need to get sorted (with green frame on image), but it sorts everything, both red and green frame on image.

Screenshot of what I want: https://ibb.co/zXQNRFs

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Range.sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj) method.

For example this sorts `F6:J12` by `G` ascending:

```js
const range = sheet.getRange('F6:J12');
range.sort({ column: range.getColumn() + 1, ascending: true });
```